# Align 2 form in a div horizontally side by side

Tags: html, css

First, a picture about my layout:

http://d.pr/qTam+

I have 2 form in a Div. The first form (#coupon) is set to float:right, the second (#comment) float:left. THe problem is with the parent div's height. It is too small, and the two form is out of this div. Why?

Comment: When you float an element, the parent no longer uses that element to calculate its width or height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `overflow: hidden` to your parent div or use a standard [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).

Comment: overflow:hidden is my friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any absolute positions, margins or paddings? They will change your layout considerably. Set them to 0 explicitly, if you are not sure.

What is your box sizes for the three divs, can you highlight those, what do you get?

Edit
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48dE2/) to understand margin and padding

Comment: The content div is: .content {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

Comment: yes that is one part, equally problamatic could be the inside float divs. You have their margin, paddings?

Comment: with overflow:hidden is OK now